# Find out given mac address is in range or not

Tags: java, mac-address

I want to know whether a given mac address is in range of specified mac addresses.

For example , i defined begin and end address . If you provide any mac address with in this range then the API has to return true otherwise false.

Eg : 70-71-BC-90-0D-01 is in range and 70-71-BC-90-0D-FF is not in range.

```
Begin address:  70-71-BC-90-00-00
End address :   70-71-BC-90-0D-F7
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the specific issue? Looks like a simple set of numeric comparisons, no?

Answer (score 5):

To be completely universal with the ranges (and not just answer to this specific range), you can create `BigInteger` instances, and compare them.

To create `BigInteger`s, we'll look at the MAC addresses as the hexadecimal representations of the numbers.

The following implementation doesn't care about:

- the "case" of hexadecimal digits (works with lower-cased, upper-cased, mixed)
- whether there are dash `'-'` separator characters in MAC addresses

The Java code:

```
BigInteger min = new BigInteger(minAddr.replace("-",""), 16);
BigInteger max = new BigInteger(maxAddr.replace("-",""), 16);

BigInteger test = new BigInteger(testAddr.replace("-",""), 16);

boolean isInRange = min.compareTo(test) <= 0 && max.compareTo(test) >= 0;
```

If you need to check many MAC addresses, you can obviously cache the `min` and `max` `BigInteger`s.

Answer (score 5):

Since 0-9 chars are "less than" A-Z chars, and all inputs are the same length, just use String comparison:

```
String beginAddress = "70-71-BC-90-00-00";
String endAddress = "70-71-BC-90-0D-F7";

if (macAddress.compareToIgnoreCase(beginAddress) >= 0
   && macAddress.compareToIgnoreCase(endAddress) <= 0)
    // in range
```

Comment: A `toUpper()` should be added to `beginAddress`, `endAdress` and `macAddress`

Comment: It's easier to use `compareToIgnoreCase(String)` than to put `toUpperCase()` before every comparison.